# How to convert datetime to date in linq query in nopcommerce c#

Tags: c#, function, date, nopcommerce

```
 query = (from s in _studentRepository.Table
     //from a in _attendanceRepository.Table.Where(j => j.StudentId == s.Id && (j.Date == date.Date)).DefaultIfEmpty()
     from a in _attendanceRepository.Table.Where(j => j.StudentId == s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
     where s.ClassSectionId == searchClassSectionId && (a.Date == Convert.ToString(date, "DD/MM/YYYY") || a.Date == null)
     select new
     {
         AttendanceTypeId = (a != null ? a.AttendanceTypeId : 0),
             Date = (a != null ? a.Date : default(DateTime)),
             Id = (a != null ? a.Id : 0),
             Student = s
     }).ToList().Select(x => new Attendance()
     {
         Id = x.Id,
         AttendanceTypeId = x.AttendanceTypeId,
         Date = x.Date,
         Student = x.Student
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Where in your code is the problem? .NET does not have a `Date` type, only `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`. Are you asking how you can display dates to users - or do you want to use only the date portion of a `DateTime` value for some other purpose? (Note that generally speaking, you should never perform date-or-datetime conversion to text/string in database queries).

Comment: Please rewrite your code so you don't mix `from`-syntax with Extension Method syntax. Also the first part of the Linq query looks like a bad attempt to perform a `JOIN`. You should rewrite your query to use `Include` or `Join` (or `GroupJoin`) instead of trying to do it yourself with nested `from x in y from a in b` statements/

Comment: c# don't have a built in type for `Date`, only for `DateTime`. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that formatting doesn't belong in the Linq query itself. The query is concerned with data, not presentation. This is happening because LINQ to Entities is trying to convert the expression tree into SQL query and .ToString(string) can not be translated into SQL. then make sure you enumerate the collection before doing your formatting. You can call .ToList(), or you can use range date.

I think the following code can help you

```
query = (from s in _studentRepository.Table
                     //from a in _attendanceRepository.Table.Where(j => j.StudentId == s.Id && (j.Date == date.Date)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 from a in _attendanceRepository.Table.Where(j => j.StudentId == s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where s.ClassSectionId == searchClassSectionId && (a.Date >= DateTime.Parse(date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Date 
                 && a.Date < DateTime.Parse(date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                 .Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1) || a.Date == null)
                 select new
                 {
                     AttendanceTypeId = (a != null ? a.AttendanceTypeId : 0),
                     Date = (a != null ? a.Date : default(DateTime)),
                     Id = (a != null ? a.Id : 0),
                     Student = s
                 }).ToList().Select(x => new Attendance()
                 {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     AttendanceTypeId = x.AttendanceTypeId,
                     Date = x.Date,
                     Student = x.Student
                 }).ToList();
```